# Is this contact form code breaking any rules?

Tags: php, html, form, email

Can you please review my PHP script below?  It is for a contact form. Am I breaking any rules?  Does it seem okay to you?

```
<?php
   session_start();

   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
      ob_start();

      if(isset(
         $_REQUEST['name'],
         $_REQUEST['email'],
         $_REQUEST['message'],
         $_REQUEST['number'],
         $_REQUEST['date'],
         $_REQUEST['select'],
         $_REQUEST['radio'],
         $_REQUEST['checkbox'],
         $_REQUEST['token'] )){

         if($_SESSION['token'] != $_POST['token']){ $response = "0";
         } else {
            $_SESSION['token'] = "";
            $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
            $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
            $message = $_REQUEST['message'];
            $number = $_REQUEST['number'];
            $date = $_REQUEST['date'];
            $select = $_REQUEST['select'];
            $radio = $_REQUEST['radio'];
            $checkbox = $_REQUEST['checkbox'];

            switch (true){
            case !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL):
                  $response = "<p style='color:red'>Invalid Email Address!</p>";
            break;

            default:
            $to = "support@loaidesign.co.uk";
            $subject = "New Message From: $name";
            $message = "Name: $name<br/>
                        Number: $number<br/>
                        Date: $date<br/>
                        Select: $select<br/>
                        Radio: $radio<br/>
                        Checkbox: $checkbox<br/>
                        Email: $email<br/>
                        Message: $message";

            $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'From: '.$email . "\r\n";
            $mailed = (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers));

            if( isset($_REQUEST['ajax'])){ $response = ($mailed) ? "1" : "0";
            }
            else{ $response = ($mailed) ? "<h2>Success!</h2>" : "<h2>Error! There was a problem with sending.</h2>";
            }
         break;
         }
         echo $response;
         }
      } else {
      echo "Error";
      }
   ob_flush();
   die();
   }
?>


<?php

       $token = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
       $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
    ?>
```

---

```
<!--Contact Form-->
<form id="contactForm" name="contactForm" action="contact.php"  method="post">
   <input name="token" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $token; ?>">
   <input name="ajax" type="hidden" value="1">

   <div class="name">
      <p>Your Name</p>
      <input name="name" class="required" autocomplete="off">
   </div>

   <div class="email-address">
      <p>Email Address</p>
      <input name="email" class="required email" autocomplete="off">
   </div>

   <div class="message">
      <p>Message</p>
      <textarea name="message" rows="5" class="required min3"></textarea>
   </div>

   <div class="number">
      <p>Phone Number</p>
      <input name="number" class="number" autocomplete="off">
   </div>

   <div class="date">
      <p>Date <small>(dd/mm/yyyy)</small></p>
      <input name="date" class="required date calendar" autocomplete="off">
   </div>

   <div class="dropdown">
      <select name="select" class="required">
         <option value="">Select</option>
         <option value="DropdownA">DropdownA</option>
         <option value="DropdownB">DropdownB</option>
      </select>
   </div>

   <div class="radio">
      <p>Radios:</p>
      <label><input name="radio" type="radio" value="male" class="required">Male</label>
      <label><input name="radio" type="radio" value="female" class="required">Female</label>
   </div>

   <div class="checkbox">
      <p>Checkboxs:</p>
      <label><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="OptionA" class="required">Option A</label>
      <label><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="OptionB" class="required">Option B</label>
   </div>

   <div>
      <p></p>
      <input name="" class="required number spamcheck">
   </div>

   <button id="submit" type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the `token` for CSRF protection and spam prevention is a good idea, especially for a form that will be generating e-mail.

This is puzzling: `<input name="ajax" type="hidden" value="1">`.  If a very basic, non-JavaScript-enabled user agent submits the HTML form, it will have `ajax=1` as a parameter.  I'd expect such a parameter to be set not by the HTML form, but by the JavaScript code that composes the AJAX request.  Even then, it's customary for the JavaScript to set an [`X-Requested-With` header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Common_non-standard_request_headers) instead of an `ajax` parameter.

From a zoomed out view, the structure of the program is:

```
<?php

    if () {
        ob_start();
        if () {
            if () {
            } else {
                switch (true) {
                    blah:
                    default:
                    // The core functionality lives here.
                }
            }
        }
        ob_flush();
        die();
    }
?>
<form>
    …
</form>
```

That's a *lot* of nesting, and it's hard to see at a glance how to reach the core functionality.  Also, I'm not a fan of `ob_start(); …; ob_flush(); die();` — any kind of killing, even if it's suicide, is a bad idea for server-side code.  Furthermore, that `switch` is a weird way to write an if-else.

Instead, I suggest wrapping the core functionality and other tests within a functions.

```
<?php
    function isCompletePost() {
        // Check for a POST containing the CSRF-prevention token
        // and the expected content fields.  Return TRUE or FALSE.
    }

    function hasValidEmailAddress() {
        // Check for valid $_REQUEST['email']
        // Return TRUE or FALSE
    }

    function sendEmail() {
        // Core functionality here.  Compose mail based on $_REQUEST
        // fields and send it.
    }

    if (isCompletePost()) {
        if (!hasValidEmailAddress()) {
            ?><p style='color:red'>Invalid Email Address!</p><?php
        } else {
            sendEmail();
        }
    } else {
?>
<form>
    …
</form>
<?php
    }
<?php>
```